# How to interpret the FLOATING_SAVE_AREA::RegisterArea field?

Tags: windows, cpu-registers, internals, x87

I got a `CONTEXT` structure by calling `GetThreadContext`. It has a `FloatSave` field, which contains the FPU status.

The `RegisterArea` field is 80 bytes long, it stores contents of the registers.

How to interpret the bytes in this array?

Is it simply ST(0), ST(1), etc. next to each other? Or is it just a raw dump of the FPU register area? (in this case I will need to read out the TOS from the status word and use it to get ST(n).)